# Preferred AVD 'survey' is not available

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run my application in eclipse it show error in console like this

Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'survey' is not available. Launching new emulator.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

how to eliminate this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Eclipse menu, choose: **Project -> Properties**

Select **Run/Debug Settings** in the left panel

Select your project in the window and select **Edit** on the right.

Select the **Target** tab.

Then you can select the first or second option.  I use the second one "Launch on all compatible devices/AVDs", because I always start up the AVD I want to use before running the project.

Answer (score 0):

create new AVD and run the application again..

Comment: I will try that one also but it's not working same problem after 4 or 5 time it's working.